# Not getting the object in the jsp send from the struts action class

Tags: jsp, struts

Hello can anybody solve this please

I'm creating the object in the action class

```
public CgUsers getUserdetail(){
        CgUsers user = userManager.getUser(id);
        return user;
        }
```

And I'm trying to use that object in the jsp page

```
c:forEach items="${Userdetail}" var="user">

               <ul>
                <li><c:out value="${user.getLastName()}"/> </li>

            </c:forEach>
```

If I try to get the output in the execute method of the action class I'm getting it right, 
but I'm not getting it in the jsp page.

And it's giving the error on the browser like

```
/WEB-INF/pages/search/profile.jsp(15,8) PWC6296: The function getLastName must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified
```

Can anybody suggest a solution? That'll be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "${**u**serdetail}" instead of "${**U**serdetail}".

Comment: Hi Marko..
I tried it but its giving the same error on the browser that is 

/WEB-INF/pages/search/profile.jsp(15,8) PWC6296: The function getLastName must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Comment: Just use user.lastName instead of user.getLastName